# GetFeature request inside WPS request fails to execute

Tags: geoserver, wfs, oracle-spatial, wps

I'm trying to make a WPS request with a GetFeature request inside of it but I'm getting an error. The idea is to get features with a spatial filter and then get a Multipolygon with the "gs:CollectGeometries". The data is stored in Oracle Database. I'm using GeoServer 2.8.0

I'll try to put all the info:

My request:

```
<wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0"
    xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
    xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0"
    xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
    xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
    <ows:Identifier>gs:CollectGeometries</ows:Identifier>
    <wps:DataInputs>
        <wps:Input>
            <ows:Identifier>features</ows:Identifier>
            <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml; subtype=wfs-collection/1.0" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wfs" method="POST">
                <wps:Body>
                    <wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.0.0"
                        xmlns:IKT="http://geoserver.hazi.eus/ikt" outputFormat="GML2"
                        xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
                        xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
                        xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
                        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/wfs.xsd">
                        <wfs:Query typeName="IKT:PACTierrasEtrs89" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#25830">
                            <Filter
                                xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
                                <Intersects>
                                    <PropertyName>GEOMETRY</PropertyName>
                                    <gml:Polygon
                                        xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
                                        <gml:outerBoundaryIs>
                                            <gml:LinearRing>
                                                <gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">533883.6330127,4709223.3703776 533755.45918457,4709024.2431803 533971.75251953,4708829.6936198 534375.72895996,4708811.3830729 534376.87336914,4709005.9326335 534258.99922364,4709223.3703776 534081.61580078,4709300.0457926 533883.6330127,4709223.3703776</gml:coordinates>
                                            </gml:LinearRing>
                                        </gml:outerBoundaryIs>
                                    </gml:Polygon>
                                </Intersects>
                            </Filter>
                        </wfs:Query>
                    </wfs:GetFeature>
                </wps:Body>
            </wps:Reference>
        </wps:Input>
    </wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:ResponseForm>
        <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="application/wkt">
            <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
        </wps:RawDataOutput>
    </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

Error response:

```
<wps:ExecuteResponse xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:lang="en" service="WPS" serviceInstance="https://sgeoserver.hazi.eus/geoserver/ows?" version="1.0.0">
    <wps:Process wps:processVersion="1.0.0">
        <ows:Identifier>gs:CollectGeometries</ows:Identifier>
        <ows:Title>Collect Geometries</ows:Title>
        <ows:Abstract>Collects the deafult geometries of the input features and combines them into a single geometry collection</ows:Abstract>
    </wps:Process>
    <wps:Status creationTime="2022-05-04T09:31:49.316Z">
        <wps:ProcessFailed>
            <ows:ExceptionReport version="1.1.0">
                <ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
                    <ows:ExceptionText>Process failed during execution
java.lang.NullPointerException</ows:ExceptionText>
                </ows:Exception>
            </ows:ExceptionReport>
        </wps:ProcessFailed>
    </wps:Status>
</wps:ExecuteResponse>
```

And turning on GeoTools level logging shows the following:

```
2022-05-04 07:58:28,822 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
2022-05-04 07:58:28,822 DEBUG [org.geotools.filter] - exporting PropertyName
2022-05-04 07:58:28,822 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2022-05-04 07:58:28,822 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2022-05-04 07:58:28,822 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - SELECT count(*) AS gt_result_ FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM NEKALUR.TBTIERRAS WHERE  SDO_RELATE(GEOMETRY, ?, 'mask=anyinteract querytype=WINDOW') = 'TRUE' ) WHERE ROWNUM <= 1000000) gt_limited_
2022-05-04 07:58:28,838 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
2022-05-04 07:58:28,838 ERROR [org.geoserver.wps.executor] - Process execution failed
org.geotools.process.ProcessException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.geotools.process.factory.AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory$InvokeMethodProcess.execute(AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory.java:565)
    at org.geoserver.wps.executor.DefaultProcessManager$ProcessCallable.call(DefaultProcessManager.java:201)
    at org.geoserver.wps.executor.DefaultProcessManager$ProcessCallable.call(DefaultProcessManager.java:169)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.geotools.data.oracle.sdo.SDO.D(SDO.java:152)
    at org.geotools.data.oracle.sdo.SDO.gType(SDO.java:121)
    at org.geotools.data.oracle.sdo.GeometryConverter.toSDO(GeometryConverter.java:158)
    at org.geotools.data.oracle.OracleDialect.setGeometryValue(OracleDialect.java:590)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.setPreparedFilterValues(JDBCDataStore.java:3426)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.setPreparedFilterValues(JDBCDataStore.java:3400)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.selectAggregateSQLPS(JDBCDataStore.java:3635)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.getAggregateValue(JDBCDataStore.java:1440)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.getCount(JDBCDataStore.java:1389)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getCountInternal(JDBCFeatureSource.java:464)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getCount(ContentFeatureSource.java:485)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureStore.getCountInternal(JDBCFeatureStore.java:183)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getCount(ContentFeatureSource.java:485)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.size(ContentFeatureCollection.java:236)
    at org.geotools.feature.collection.DecoratingSimpleFeatureCollection.size(DecoratingSimpleFeatureCollection.java:113)
    at org.geotools.data.crs.ForceCoordinateSystemFeatureResults.size(ForceCoordinateSystemFeatureResults.java:106)
    at org.geotools.process.vector.CollectGeometries.execute(CollectGeometries.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.geotools.process.factory.AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory$InvokeMethodProcess.execute(AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory.java:549)
    ... 6 more
2022-05-04 07:58:28,838 INFO [org.geoserver.wps] - 
Request: execute
    service = WPS
    version = 1.0.0
    baseUrl = http://sgeoserver.hazi.eus:80/geoserver/
    identifier:
        value = gs:CollectGeometries
    dataInputs:
        input[0]:
            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@2dd32dce (value: features, codeSpace: null)
            reference = net.opengis.wps10.impl.InputReferenceTypeImpl@36446e3 (body: net.opengis.wfs.impl.GetFeatureTypeImpl@2c69e2d2 (handle: null, service: WFS, version: 1.0.0, baseUrl: null, providedVersion: null, extendedProperties: {}) (maxFeatures: null, outputFormat: GML2, resultType: results, traverseXlinkDepth: null, traverseXlinkExpiry: null, formatOptions: null, metadata: null, startIndex: null, viewParams: null), encoding: null, href: http://geoserver/wfs, method: POST, mimeType: text/xml, schema: null)
    responseForm:
        rawDataOutput:
            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@5baa5fc5 (value: result, codeSpace: null)
            mimeType = application/wkt
2022-05-04 07:58:28,853 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation  only.
2022-05-04 07:58:28,853 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
```

The strange thing is that the GetFeature request works fine on its own but when I try to do all inside the WPS request I get this error. Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: that's an oracle error - probably on `SELECT count(*) AS gt_result_ FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM NEKALUR.TBTIERRAS WHERE  SDO_RELATE(GEOMETRY, ?, 'mask=anyinteract querytype=WINDOW') = 'TRUE' ) WHERE ROWNUM <= 1000000) gt_limited_`

Comment: Hi, yes, it looks like an Oracle error, but if i make only the getfeature request I get the expeceted response, but if it's inside the WPS request it throws that error... I'm supposing the wps request is ok, isn't it right? Thanks.

Comment: I've just checked that if I make the whole request (WPS+GETFEATURE) without spatial filter (intersects) and filtering by attribute it works fine ...

Comment: does the oracle log have anything to add?

Comment: If you really mean 2.8 then you need to upgrade to 2.20

Comment: Unfortunately switching to 2.20 right now is not an option.. thus I'll have to think on another workaround.,.

Comment: I do not see any syntax error on that statement. IMO, the exception happens when trying to convert the GML geometry in your query window to SDO_GEOMETRY. That GML geometry appears not to have any coordinate system, which is very odd.

Comment: Hi, even though I set te srs in the Polygon definition `<gml:Polygon srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#25830" 
                                            xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">` I still get the same error... I'm just following the example in https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/downloads/releases/2.8.x-ld/doc/filter/filter_reference.html?highlight=intersects